# How to detect if someone is using airmon-ng [Aircrack-ng] in my wi-fi network

Tags: wifi, kali-linux, defense

Using the Linux Kali distribution, I was able to get the password from my wifi network using the `airmon-ng` [Aircrack-ng] tool.

However, how can I find out if someone is doing this on my network?

Comment: Eventually answered here? https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/19327/what-does-wep-access-point-show-during-aircrack-ng-attack

Comment: By "password from my wifi network" do you mean the password FOR your network? Or do you mean the password for another application which was communicating over the wifi nework?

Comment: @user52472 I did not understand very well, but, it is not of another application, but the password of my wifi network. I was able to figure out the password for my Wi-Fi network using Aircrack-ng. However, I was in doubt about how to prevent anyone from doing the same.

Comment: Ok.  What type of authentication is your network using.  WEP? WPA?

Comment: @user52472 WAP authentication.

Comment: @AlexandreN. If you use WPA, why do you worry about someone trying to crack WEP?

Comment: I'm worried about WAP

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't tell if they're doing it because they are scanning your network promiscuously, which means they are just monitoring traffic and not generating any of their own.

You **can** normally prevent this type of attack by using an appropriate level of encryption and passphrase sizes, something such as WPA2-PSK instead of WPA.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you're using WPA authentication, the best thing you can do is have a strong passphrase.  WPA is not vulnerable to the same Fluhrer, Mantin, and Shamir key recovery attack that WEP is vulnerable to, but it's still possible to brute force the passphrase offline by capturing the WPA 4 way handshake, so it all boils down to how good your passphrase is.  The longer it is, the better it is.